# Deriving Properties of an Estimator with Jensen's Inequality

Tags: variance, expected-value, bias, mse

I have an estimator, N* = (NH*) / H, where N (specimens sampled in figure below) and H (Unique Haplotypes) are constants and H* is random, but can be treated equivalently to the sample maximum X_(n). Also H* >= H. I would like to derive properties of such an estimator (e.g., bias, variance, MSE). The idea is that when H = H*, then N* = N and no further sampling is required. This situation would correspond to the curve essentially plateauing.

I provide an illustration below.

[image]

Essentially, what I am looking to do is derive an estimator to predict the sample size (N* - displayed on the x-axis) that corresponds to the the curve reaching an asymptote (i.e., the point where the slope of the curve becomes 0, or not significantly different from 0).

Assuming N* ~ Discrete Uniform(N, theta) (clearly not reasonable from the barplot), it is easy to derive a (method of moments) estimator for theta in terms of N and H, and I have done so, along with other estimator properties. For H* it is H* = (H*(H + 1)) / 2.

Using the uniform estimator with N = 240 and H = 15 and H* = 120, I get N* = 1920.

Using information from the curve, the maximum of H is 11 and my presumption is that the curve will saturate at H = 15. So, I have N* = (240*15)/11 = 328, which seems more reasonable, but make no distributional assumptions, hence is a nonparametric estimator.

Can anyone provide a workaround or a potential solution? Hopefully this is clear. Or perhaps a method already exists to find such an estimate that I am not aware of?

Comment: Since $NH^{*}/H=(N/H)H^{*}$ is just a constant times $H^{*}$, it would seem there is no difficulty at all in relating the bias and variance of $N^{*}$ to those of $H^{*}$. Are you sure you have described your notation as intended?

Comment: @whuber I think I see my fault - if I let p = H / H* this is equivalent to           p = X / n, but n is just a constant, while X is the random variable. I have made a slight addition to my post. H* can be equated to the sample maximum X_(n).

Comment: You question is still puzzling, because it remains the case that $N^{*}$ merely is a constant multiple of $H^{*}$. Moreover, it makes no sense to speak of this as an "estimator" until you explain what it is trying to estimate.  However, assuming--as you strongly imply--you can derive any relevant properties of $H^{*}$, the corresponding properties of $N^{*}$ are trivially easy to obtain. What, then, requires a "workaround" or "solution"?

Comment: @whuber Forgive my naivete. I just came up with the idea and not being a statistician per se. Perhaps an illustration and a bit further explanation would make this easier. I will add the details.

Comment: Multiplying measurements by a constant is exactly the same thing (mathematically) as changing your units, such as converting from kilograms to pounds.  Thus, your question *sounds* like it's asking "if I can compute the bias/variance/MSE/etc. of an estimator in kilograms, then how can I find a workaround for computing the same property in pounds?"

Comment: @whuber See my post edit above. I'd like to use the data itself to derive an estimator rather than assuming a parametric form for H* (and hence N*, since H* is the RV). Not being a theoretical statistician, I am not certain if this is entirely possible...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65426/discussion-between-jarrett-phillips-and-whuber).